# Matching array entries in AWS Cloudwatch log metrics filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have JSON strings upload to AWS Cloudwatch logs and am now trying to write a filter that generates metrics from those logs.

Suppose I have JSON like the following:

```
{"test_results": [{"result": "success", "name": "foo", "nr_failed": 0}, {"result": "failure", "name": "bar", "nr_failed": 3}]}
```

The AWS Cloudwatch log metrics filter allows me to specify a pattern like the following:

```
{ $.test_results[0].result = "failure" }
```

The above means, "match the entire line if the zeroth entry in the value of 'test_results' has a
value of 'failure' for its 'result' field". In this particular case, the zeroth entry had a result
of 'success', so it wouldn't match. But this next line would match:

```
{ $.test_results[1].result = "failure" }
```

Now suppose I want to match the whole line if *any* of the entries had a value of 'failure'.
Basically, I want to do this:

```
{ $.test_results[*].result = "failure" }
```

But the pattern syntax doesn't seem to allow wildcards in the array index.
How can I match lines where any of the result values are "failure" ?

Alternatively, how could I pick out the numeric values for all the "nr_failed" fields in the "test_results" array and create metrics from those?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Is there any known solution to this issue?

Comment: no solution to this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, according to the [official AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#metric-filters-extract-json) there's no syntax to address your issue explicitly:

> The elements in arrays follow a zero-based numbering system, meaning that the first element in the array is element 0, the second element is element 1, and so on. Enclose elements in brackets ("[]").

However there's a little hack that might be helpful for somebody who also looks for the solution.
You might build query with OR (`||`) operator to check every item in the list:

```
{$.test_results[0].result = failure || $.test_results[1].result = failure}
```

Moreover, it does work even if actual list length is less than number of conditional arguments.
So, we have to set the upper limit for the length of `test_results` and generate query for that.

Let's say the length of `test_results` would be less than 10 elements then let's generate the query with Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "{"; for i in {0..10}; do echo -n "$.test_results[$i].result = failure"; test "$i" -ne "10" && echo -n " || "; done; echo "}"
```

But let you know: **the length of query should be less or equal to 1024 chars to work**.

Answer (score -2):

I found just using "failure" as a metric filter worked, it isn't particularly elegant but it might work for you.

[image]

Comment: This just looks for the `failure` string anywhere

Comment: It does yes, but based on the information presented it might suffice.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Op is looking for the `failure` value in any of the result entries